# How can I securely install an older version of Chrome on a device that won't support newer versions?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, security, chrome-for-android, apk, unknown-sources

I have an [Android device](http://www.onyx-international.com/index.php/en/boox-products/boox-i-series) that runs Android 4.0.2 and can't be updated any further.

When I tried to install Chrome from the Play Store, I was told:

> Your device isn't compatible with this version.

Indeed, [Google says](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/7026064?hl=en&rd=1&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=1):

> Chrome is available on phones and tablets running Android 4.1+ (Jelly Bean). If you're **on Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich), Chrome version 42 and lower will work**, but you won’t get any updates to Chrome.

Fine by me, I can run and older version of Chrome. But where can I download the APK? A Google search for `Chrome 42 Android` gives me a lot of domains that I don't trust. I generally try to avoid installing or running executables from sources I'm not familiar with.

From Googles quote above, they seem to recommend that people on 4.0 run older versions of Chrome. But do they provide the APK? Or does any other trustworthy source provide it?

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/135711/131868

Comment: I would suggest being very careful with older versions of internet browsers. I would imagine they will not contain all the security updates and therefore leave your device vulnerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/chrome/chrome-42-0-2311-111-release/chrome-42-0-2311-111-4-android-apk-download/

I use APK mirror all the time and have never had any issues.  You said 42 and below right? This is version 42

Comment: [Looks OK.](https://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/apkmirror.com?utm_source=addon&utm_content=rw-viewsc)

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/135711/131868

Comment: Glad I could help! Cheers!

Comment: Give either of these a shot http://www.apkmirror.com/?s=Google+Chrome+42&post_type=app_release&searchtype=apk