# Is it possible to update android version in Motorola xoom tablet?

Tags: updates, motorola

I have a tablet of Motorola ([XOOM MZ604](https://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_xoom_mz604-3833.php)), it is rather old but for me looks and behaves like new, except of one big problem that I cannot install important applications on it because the android version of the android there doesn't support those applications (such as google docs). My question is if it possible at all to update the version of the android in this tablet, and if it is possible then how to do that?

By searching on this site I found the following 2 questions and answers ([This question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/148367/how-can-i-securely-install-an-older-version-of-chrome-on-a-device-that-wont-sup) + [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/167188/install-google-chrome-for-old-tablet-phone)) but they don't help me because the answers there are about chrome while my wish is to update the version of the android. Beside of that, I've searched a lot on google but not really found an answer to my question. I'll appreciate a lot a clear answer.

[image]

Comment: As I see latest version provided by manufacturer is 4.0.4 so dead end there, you can try searching for custom ROM for your device.

Comment: Thank you. After reading your comment I've looked for it on Google and I found myself complicated in this issue. I've entered a lot of forums but the links don't work and those who work contains viruses. If you know custom ROM for my device kindly let me know.

Comment: [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/motorola-xoom) maybe?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The links don't work or send me to ali express. I appreciate your help.