# How come apps showed up in apkmirror before I can download it in Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store, apk

I have been checking and waiting for Pokemon Go 0.45 for several hours, and now it is 11pm Pacific Time and it is still not available on my Android phone or on the Google Play website. However, it is on the [apkmirror website](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/niantic-inc/pokemon-go/pokemon-go-0-45-0-release/pokemon-go-0-45-0-android-apk-download/) and it says:

> Uploaded November 6, 2016 at 4:21PM PST

So it was uploaded 7 hours ago to apkmirror?  How is that possible and can it be trusted?

Answer (score 1):

[I would trust apkmirror.com](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/135711/is-apkmirror-com-safe)

> So it was uploaded 7 hours ago to apkmirror? How is that possible and can it be trusted?

The app appears on the apkmirror.com because some apps are not rolling out globally at once so appearantly someone living in another area got update before you and upload the file on the website.

Comment: at least 7 hours of lag, and for the US market?

Comment: I'm also using the US market but most apps show up late. Sometimes I saw in the news about certain apps get updated but doesn't appear in my update list for a period of time.

Comment: so maybe either the US is not an important market... or another possibility is they want other countries to be the guinea pig first