# Move data (without cloud storage) from CM 13.0 to LineageOS

Tags: cyanogenmod, data-transfer, lineageos

My current phone is running **CM 13.0**. I have a new phone ready, running **LineageOS**. What's the simplest way to move all data (most important: contacts, pictures, mail + configuration, SMS) to the new phone?

Both phones do not have Google services installed and I don't want to move my data to the cloud. I tried to make a `adb backup` on the one phone and a restore on the other phone. I did not run into an error, but I also did not see the data on the new phone. I would be happy to pay a small fee for a decent tool, but without access to the play store, most apps are not an option.

Comment: You want to move app data or media files (pictures files videos etc) ?

Comment: I want to move both kinds: I guess contacts, sms, ... are app data and pictures are media files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First and foremost**: provided that you trust 3rd-party APK provider sites (APKPure, APKMirror, etc.), no Play Store access is not a problem - you will only be restricted from paid apps. For trust issues read [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/135711/is-apkmirror-com-safe) (and others related) on the site.

**Contacts**:

- In the Contacts app, top-right menu - `import/export` - `export to .vcf file`.
- Select items you want exported.
- A .vcf file will be saved by default to the root of the internal storage - back it up somewhere.
- Import later with the `import from .vcf file` option.

**SMS**: use the app SMS Backup and Restore. Been using the Pro version of the app since Android 4.x and it always worked smoothly. Backed-up content will be stored in the `SMSBackupRestore` folder under internal storage. [APKMirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/carbonite/sms-backup-restore/)

**Mail**: your mail is supposed to be all up in the clouds, i.e. synched with your mail server, so there should be no need of backing them up in the first place.

**Media files** (picture, music, etc.): provided that you know the location, just copy them off the device. Use the `details` option in the Gallery app if you need help locating a specific picture.

**App data**: the free version of Titanium Backup is enough for backing up individual apps' data. Backed-up content will be stored in the `TitaniumBackup` folder under internal storage. Note that, before restoring app data, you might have to start them once. [APKMirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/titanium-track/titanium-backup/)

Copy backed-up contents off the device (keep folder structures intact), then after flashing LOS, copy them back in place, and use respective restore options.

Answer (score 0):

Pictures and other media you can move by plugging both phones in PC via USB and manually transfer it. Since you "killed" all other options. Contacts can be transfered by taking backup on old phone (there is option for that in contacts app, don't know where exactly) and transfer file to new phone (example Bluetooth) and import contacts from backup in contacts app. For sms i'm not sure if it can be done like for contacts, but you can look in settings of messaging app (I personally don't have option but who on Earth backup SMS?) If you have something important in few messages just take screenshots and move with other pictures, or copy it and save in the file. 
However I don't see other way to do this since you killed all options.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is you can take entire backup of your phone using **titanium backup** it works pretty well if you use it correctly. It has two version one works with **rooted phones** and other without. You cannot expect much features in free versions though you can buy paid version if you need more info on how to backup in detail check out their official site for pro version : [Titanium Backup Pro Official Site](https://titaniumbackuppro.com)