# Install a fully functional Audible app on Android older than Android 6.0

Tags: android-versions, compatibility, audible

I just bought a Samsung Galaxy S5 Mini, featuring Android 5.1. However, I cannot install the "Audible" audiobook app via Google Play (no search results).

I know that this should work, as I have the exact same device (bought earlier) where Audible is running (automatic app updates are switched off)

I tried downloading an older version (Audible-2.16.1) from [www.apkmirror.com](http://www.apkmirror.com) (not sure if the website is trustworthy) and installed it manually using ADB and USB debugging. The app kind of worked. At least I could log in and see my audiobooks. However, when trying to download any of the books, I get error messages.

I assume that the app tries to connect to the wrong (old) server when downloading.

Does anybody else have similar problems and knows how to get Audible going on older devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Audible 3.0.1 ([APK Mirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/audible-inc/audiobooks-from-audible/audiobooks-from-audible-3-0-1-release/)) is the latest version that supports Android 4.1+** before it jumped to requiring a minimum Android version of Android 6.0.

---

Some additional clarifications to the question:

1. Since Audible 3.1.0 (March 25, 2021), the minimum Android version jumped to Android 6.0. This affects the app's visibility in [the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.audible.application) since *incompatible apps will not be shown when searching directly from the app*.
2. The major version jump from 2.x to 3.x possibly indicates a breaking change including on the backend server-side, thus *Audible apps before 3.0.0 might not work properly anymore*.
3. Last but not least, [APK Mirror is considered trustworthy](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/135711/44325).